# 'Workout' object has no attribute 'exercises'

Tags: python, django

I just started to play with Django trying to make an API REST, for some reason that i don't understand i'm getting this error `'Workout' object has no attribute 'exercises'` when i do `GET - /workouts`.

I'm using *Django REST framework* to make this thing.

This is part of my code that I think you need to help me:

serializers.py

```
class WorkoutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    exercises = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Workout
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'creation_date', 'exercises']

class ExerciseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Exercise
        fields = ['url', 'video_url', 'workout']
```

models.py

```
class Workout(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Exercise(models.Model):
    video_url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    workout = models.ForeignKey(Workout, related_name='workout', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.video_url)
```

views.py

```
class WorkoutViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Workout.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WorkoutSerializer

class ExerciseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows exercises to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Exercise.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExerciseSerializer
```

Comment: You are using `related_name='workout'` wrong, Related name allows you to specify what name the related collection should have on the workout object, so in your case this sohuld be `related_name='exercises'`. You can read more about this there https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: Wow, it worked. Love you man, thanks.